# Create a dictionary from a list of lists VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of objects within another list. It looks like this:

```
Dim _elements as List(Of List(Of Element))
```

- _elements(0) is a list of Element1, Element2, etc.
- _elements(1) is a list of Element5, Element6, etc.

I need to create a dictionary of the elements so that the index of each list is the Key in the dictionary. The value of the dictionary should hold all elements of the Legend type that can be found in the list. Something like the following:

```
Dim legendElements As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Element))
' Initialize the list in the dictionary
For i As Integer = 0 To _elements.Count - 1
   legendElements(i) = new List(Of Element)
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To _elements.Count - 1
   For each element as Element in _elements(i)
      If element.GetType() Is GetType(Legend) Then
         legendElements.add(element)
      End If
   Next
Next
```

Is there a System.Linq function that can do the equivalent as the example above?

Comment: The objects in the list may be inherited from different types of Elements. For example, there may be a Legend element or a Map element (just to name a few). In the example. I would like to be able to create a list of only the Legend elements in the list of lists. Yes, it could be possible that there may be two Legend elements in the same secondary list. I will clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0) method to get a flatten list of the target type which you filter by calling the [`Enumerable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) method. Call the [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0) method to create from the result `IEnumerable` of anonymous objects to  hold and pass the `Legend` objects along with their indices, and finally, call the [`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0) method to create
`Dictionary(Of Integer, Element)` from the anonymous objects.

```vb
Dim legendElements As Dictionary(Of Integer, Element) = elements.
    SelectMany(Function(x) x.Where(Function(y) y.GetType Is GetType(Legend))).
    Select(Function(v, k) New With {Key .Key = k, .Value = v}).
    ToDictionary(Function(a) a.Key, Function(a) a.Value)
```

Do the proper cast if you need a `Dictionary(Of Integer, Legend)`.

```vb
Dim legendElements As Dictionary(Of Integer, Legend) = elements.
    SelectMany(Function(x) x.Where(Function(y) y.GetType Is GetType(Legend))).
    Select(Function(v, k) New With {Key .Key = k, .Value = v}).
    ToDictionary(Function(a) a.Key, Function(a) DirectCast(a.Value, Legend))
```